# Logstash Docker with pipelines.yml

Tags: logstash, pipeline

I've been trying to get a Logstash Docker container (docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash-oss:6.0.0) to run with multiples pipelines using pipelines.yml, but I can't get it running. Here follows my Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash-oss:6.0.0
RUN rm -f /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf
RUN rm -f /usr/share/logstash/config/pipelines.yml
ADD pipeline/ /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/
COPY pipelines.yml /usr/share/logstash/config/pipelines.yml
```

If I add logstash.conf inside pipeline/ it will run, but will ignore pipelines.yml.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hey @ademarizu, did you find a solution for your Dockerfile? How should the structure/order be? I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

How are you running logstash? If you want to use the pipelines.yml file to drive pipeline configuration, you must start logstash like `bin/logstash` with neither `-f` (`--config.path`) nor `-e` (`--config.string`).

More information here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/master/multiple-pipelines.html#multiple-pipelines

Comment: I haven't change the entrypoint nor the command from the original logstash image file.  I'm just calling `docker run --name logstash mylogstash`.

Comment: An issue has been opened to track this issue https://github.com/elastic/logstash-docker/issues/64.

You can set the built-in `path.config` to null, there's an example in the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is also necessary not to specify `path.config` or `config.string` setting in your `logstash.yml` file.